# blueimp jQuery-File-Upload Undefined index: CONTENT_LENGTH

Tags: php, blueimp, jquery-file-upload

I am testing working example from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/

When I run it on php-5.4.14-Win32-VC9-x86 , I get

`*Undefined index: CONTENT_LENGTH in server\php\UploadHandler.php on lin 392*`.

Can you suggest what is wrong? something to do with php.ini ?

Link: [server/php/UploadHandler.php](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think blueimp jQuery-File-Upload was tested on linux apache php as for windows apache and php we have to add before Line 392

```
if ( !isset( $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] ) )
    $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] = '';
```